# How to find backup database for Ambari?

Tags: ambari, hdf

Our system is configured Ambari with some database. But I am not sure which database is backed up for Ambari.

1. When I went through the installation procedure, I could see the steps for MariaDB and MySQL is installed.
2. When I checked ambari.properties file under the path '/etc/ambari-server/conf', I could see the line with **server.jdbc.database=mysql**

Basically, How to check which database is connected for Ambari and how to confirm?

grep db /etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties | grep name

```
custom.mysql.jdbc.name=mysql-connector-java.jar
previous.custom.mysql.jdbc.name=mysql-connector-java.jar
server.jdbc.database_name=ambari
server.jdbc.rca.user.name=ambari
server.jdbc.user.name=ambari
```

grep db /etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties | grep database

```
server.jdbc.database=mysql
server.jdbc.database_name=ambari
```

Answer (score 1):

Ambari database name should be in `/etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties`, along with other connection details to the db.

You can use something like following to grep the db name:-

```
grep db /etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties | grep name
```

Comment: Please check the output of the command in the description

Comment: Ambari is the name of database that is ambari using

Comment: all you are missing is the host, which is likely localhost to the ambari-server (master node).  @rikamamanus has provided the answer, pls accept.